# Как включить автодополнение для своего скрипта?

Tags: linux, bash, autocomplete

Допустим, у меня есть простой скрипт, который является обёрткой для команды, для которой есть автодополнение.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo "useful"
ls $1
```

Если вводить `ls`+<kbd>TAB</kbd>, то автодополнение директории есть. Как сделать такое же автодополнение для моего скрипта, **не меняя конфиг пользователя**? И возможно ли это? Чтобы просто скинуть мой скрипт на другой комп/виртуалку, все настройки были внутри скрипта, и автодополнение заработало.

Comment: Посмотрите эти две статьи с примерами: [https://habr.com/ru/post/71525/](https://habr.com/ru/post/71525/) [https://habr.com/ru/post/115886/](https://habr.com/ru/post/115886/)